# Как в шорткоде добавить ID пользователя wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Использую плагин UsersWP, и с помощью шорткода вывожу под каждой статьей подписаться на автора таким образом: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[uwp_follow_user title="Подписаться" user_id="3"]'); ?>` 
но я только подпишусь на автора с ИД=3 а надо чтоб ид подставлялось автоматически для каждого автора.
может кто знаете какие-то хуки или вызов функции из этого плагина

Comment: Нужно использовать `get_the_author_meta('ID')` и подставлять в шорткод `<?php echo do_shortcode('[uwp_follow_user title="Подписаться" user_id="' . get_the_author_meta('ID') . '"]'); ?>`